# Podcast app opens feed url type

Tags: ios, objective-c, url-scheme, rss-reader, podcast

I made an app which is able to open RSS Feeds. I registered the feed:// URL scheme in my app target and implemented the `application:openURL:sourceApplication:annotation:` method. But when I click on a RSS Feed on a website, the podcasts app handles the request.
How do I get my application to open the URL?

Answer (score 1):

This isn't a bug. The URL scheme `feed` is used by Apple. You will need to select a different name for your URL scheme. URL scheme names should be very specific, not general such as `feed` to avoid conflicting with other apps the user may have installed on their device.

Comment: So how can this be handled, if I want to make sure an RSS feed is opened in a specific application?

Answer (score 0):

Submit a radar to apple. No workaround so far.